# How to make only posts show date

Tags: posts

Made template but how to make date to show only in posts not anywhere else?

```
<div class="date"><strong><?php the_date(); ?></strong></div>
```

This makes date to show in Home, Pages but i need only for posts.
Something like if is post then the_date(); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Create a separate `single.php` for posts and show the date there only.
2. Use a condition:

```php
if ( is_single() )
{
?><div class="date"><strong><?php the_date(); ?></strong></div><?php
}
```

Comment: So i put it in Index and from Main page also date was not showing.
I was trying some more searches and figured a little bit about php and some tests until working and made like this-
`<?php if (is_page()) {
  }
else { ?> <div class="date"><strong><?php the_date(); ?></strong></div> <?php } ?>`
You also helped to understand more WP and PHP THX :)